# Rows and Column's Not working in my python code

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Something as simple as this

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

root.title('Trees!')
root.geometry('500x500')

Welcome = Label(root, text='Hello! Here you can learn all about trees!')
Welcome.config(font=('Elephant', 11))
Welcome.grid(row=0, column=1)

Search = Entry(root)
#Search.grid(row=2)




root.mainloop()
```

Wont work, it will only go down 1 row and no columns, please help as this is really annoying and this is just as simple as it seems.

Comment: It appears to be working fine. What output are you expecting? You can use ASCII, draw or paint an image illustrating how you expect the result to appear.

Comment: For me, it doesnt move it stays locked in Nw location no matter what i try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty rows and empty columns have a size of zero. You could put something at 1000,1000, but if the other 999 rows and columns are empty it's still going to appear in the upper-left corner.

Comment: So how would i fix this?

Comment: @bossotron13: that all depends on what you want to do. You didn't make it clear what sort of layout you're wanting to create. The short answer to your question is "put something in the empty rows and columns", though that's not the only way to adjust the size of rows and columns.

Comment: So would a good idea be to just put white text in the column i want but really down in rows so it doesn't affect the rest?

Comment: @bossotron13: no, that's almost never the right solution. It's impossible to give good advice without knowing what you're trying to accomplish.